# Integrating and showing equal to some quantity

Tags: integration, analysis, summation

Define 
$G_N(z)=(\ \dfrac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi } )\   (\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}(-1 )^n sgn(n)(\ (z-n)^{-1}+n^{-1}   )\ -\sum_{m=-N}^{m=N}(-1)^msgn(m)m^{-1} $

I want to show that $G_N(z)=\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}sgn(n) \dfrac{\sin \pi(z-n)}{\pi (z-n)}$
Can you please give any suggestion??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
\begin{align}
G_N(z)  & = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\mathrm{sgn}(n)(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
 & = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\mathrm{sgn}(n)(-1)^n\frac{1}{z-n}\\
 & = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}\mathrm{sgn}(n)\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}(-1)^n\frac{1}{z-n}.
\end{align}
By noting that $$\sin(\pi(z-n))=\sin(\pi z) \cos(\pi n)-\cos(\pi z)\sin(\pi n),$$ and using $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$, and $\sin(\pi n) = 0$, we arrive at
$$G_N(z) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}\mathrm{sgn}(n)\frac{\sin(\pi (z-n))}{\pi(z-n)}.$$